# Glowroot Api is very hard to handle in terms of building

Tags: java, glowroot

I downloaded GLOWROOT code source from their GitHub repository
[https://github.com/glowroot/glowroot] then I build the project .
My main goal is to do some modification to the errors section because I am not in need to trace the errors section .

So I built the application and it was too many several jars on every location of the project which made it hard for me to handle and to re-arrange it in a manner to deploy it within my WILDFLY 15 application Server.

I tried to see if I can do anything  on the binary distribution but as far as I understand the UI gets generated in the application deployment and it is not accessible from outside .

I opened an issue about this like a service request to get some clarifications but no response .

I would prefer a solution that handles the issue within the GLOWROOT project that I cloned from the git repository .

Thanks a lot for your time and your help .

I tried to change the UI and re-arrange the project to deploy it .

and jars were a lot I didn't know even how to arrange them in a deployable way .